# Keras : Gradients of output w.r.t. input as input to classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am doing research and for an experiment I want to use gradients of a specific layer in the network with respect to the network's input( similar as guided backprop) as input to another network (classifier). The goal is to 'force' network to change 'attention' according to classifier, so those two networks should be trained simultaneously.

I implemented it on this way :

```
input_tensor = model.input
output_tensor = model.layers[-2].output
grad_calc = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:K.gradients(x,input_tensor)[0],output_shape=(256,256,3),trainable=False)(output_tensor)
pred = classifier(grad_calc)
out_model = Model(input_tensor,pred)
```

out_model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001),metrics=['accuracy'])

Then, when I try to train the model

```
out_model.train_on_batch(imgs,np.zeros((imgs.shape[0],2)))
```

it is not working. It seems that it stucks there, nothing is happening (no error nor other message).

I am not sure is this right way to implement this, so I would be very thankful if someone with more experience can take a look and give me advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I was trying to achieve that I would swith to plain Tensorflow and something along the lines:

```
#build model
input = tf.placeholder()
net   = tf.layesr.conv2d(input, 12)
loss  = tf.nn.l2_loss(net)
step  = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

# now inspect your graph and select the gradient tensor you are looking for
for op in tf.get_default_graph.get_operations():
    print(op.name)
grad = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("enqueue")

with tf.Session as sess:
    _, grad, input = sess.run([step, grad, input], ...)
    # feed your grad and input into another network
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you think that something like this is not possible in Keras? Rest of my project (models) is written in Keras...

Comment: The problem with Keras model above was in BatchNormalization layer. When I removed it from the model, I am able to run train_on_batch. It seems that BatchNormalization runs in infinite recursion.